# C# Find Image on Screen and click on it

Tags: c#, python

I'm interested if I can detect an image on the screen (specific Image) and click on it in real-time (I give an image before activating it and it clicks on it)

I would like to know how to do it in C# but other languages appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be achieved with basic javascript. If you know what image you want to click on checkout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

### C#:

If I were to go about this, I would use a function that got the color at a certain pixel, and matched that to that of the image. Here's how you can do that in `C#`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr window);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr dc, int x, int y);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr window, IntPtr dc);

public static Color GetColorAt(int x, int y) {
    IntPtr desk = GetDesktopWindow();
    IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(desk);
    int a = (int)GetPixel(dc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(desk, dc);
    return Color.FromArgb(255, (a >> 0) & 0xff, (a >> 8) & 0xff, (a >> 16) & 0xff);
}
```

Then you can easily get a pixel color anywhere by calling `Console.WriteLine(GetColorAt(x, y));`. If you have an image in mind, you can use this method to plot what colors lie inside the picture and then simply create a `for` loop to scan the entire screen until it matches that color/array of colors. Once you've located the image you could create a click event like at [Auto Clicker C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32556/Auto-Clicker-C).

Answer (score 0):

### Java:

If using `Java` is an option, I've made one of these before. Basically what you want to do is figure out which colors are inside the image of choice and input that into the code so that it can look for it.

To get the color of the pixel at a location use:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);

int rgb = capture.getRGB(x, y); // Get colors of screen

// Convert int to specific colors
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = (rgb) & 0xFF;
```

Then you can put this into an `if` function to detect if the color matches that which you're looking for:

```
if (red == whateverRedYouWant && green == whateverGreenYouWant && blue == whateverBlueYouWant) {
    robot.mouseMove(x, y); // Move mouse to that position
    robot.setAutoDelay(250);

    // Click the mouse
    robot.mousePress(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Note that if you don't know where the image might be, you'll want a `for` loop to scan the whole screen checking each pixel for the predetermined color/array of colors you've found in the image.

Comment: I've never tried Java before, could you explain to me a bit?

Comment: @Retr0 [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))

Comment: while I imported the code you gave, it gave me an error with the capture and the x,y

Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: @Retr0 Did you input coordinates into the `x, y`?

Comment: What shall I insert there? I've never used Java before.

Comment: @Retr0 the `x, y` variables are coordinates on your screen like `330, 450`. Screens are measured in pixels (like 1920x1080) and that coordinate value tells the program where to look on the screen.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to remove most of the errors, one of the errors I have no idea how to remove is ```Robot robot = new Robot();```

Comment: Ok after trying to find some code that using robot it didn't gave me an error, yet in the console I got this: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
 at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)```