# C# Fastest way to if detect image/pixels on screen and click

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, macros, bots

As title, I'm looking for something that could detect fastly if an image, or a pixel / pixel area, appears on the screen, and then click it, before it disappear.
I also searched for some nuget packages but it seems there's no much things.
This job is made by tons of mini-tools, especially macros tools, I think it's not hard to achieve it but actually I have no idea on how to proceed.
Any hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend that you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61126792/11507778) to use windows api to detect if the image appears on the screen.